# Image Processing: Problem with Fish measuring

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection, contour

I'm having problems with contouring a live video capture. I'm using **OpenCV** library on **Python**

My **objective** is to measure tilapia fishes that go through a tube one by one and get their approx sizes by getting the rectangle dimensions. [Here](https://streamable.com/ykyq7) is a sample of 1 tilapia passing.

[Here](https://streamable.com/5umk1) is one more with **backlighting**

The **problem** is that the water is also detected as a contour and I can't seem to isolate the fish. I have tried using a mix of blurring techniques, dilation, erosion but it can't seem to solve my problem.

Are there any other algorithms I can use? Or should I switch to ***Object Detection?***

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('white.mp4')

foreground_background = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if(type(frame) == type(None)):
        break
    gray                 = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #gray                = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21, 21), 0)
    #gray                = cv2.medianBlur(gray,11)
    gray                 = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray,9,75,75)
    ret,thresh           = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255 , cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    thresh               = cv2.erode(thresh, kernel, iterations=3)
    thresh               = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=3)
    im2, cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    c=None
    for c in cnts:

         (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
         cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 255, 0), 2)         

    cv2.imshow('Output', thresh)
    cv2.waitKey(2)

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Following added by Mark Setchell... if anyone wants to see the individual frames, I extracted at 10 fps and montaged the frames as follows:

[image]

Commands used:

```
ffmpeg -i a.mov  -r 10 frame_%05d.png
montage -tile 6x frame_*png -geometry +10+10  result.png
```

Comment: I’ve worked on a similar problem many years ago. It’s always best to simplify image analysis tasks by improving the image acquisition. In this case I’d set up a system where an optical trigger causes a high-res camera to take a single picture of the fish as it comes past the lens. You are using a shitty low-res camera with lots of compression artifacts, that’s never a good start.

Comment: can you show me the final contour of your process? Maybe i can help you with the isolation if the fish is big enough to be differentiated.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my editing your question, just click `edit` and delete my additions if you object to them. I just wanted to show the individual frames so folks can see what they are dealing with and maybe you'll be more likely to get an answer.

Comment: No I don't mind at all! Thank you.

Comment: I've added 1 more example of fish passing with backlighting.

Answer (score 0):

I would try several things including:

1. **Various ways to remove the background** -- I see you used *cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()* but simpler methods might yield better results.  Try taking the average of several dozen frames when there are no fish in the frame and then subtract that *average background* from all frames.  Something like this: background = (A+B+C)/3 where A, B, and C are background frames/matrices without fish.  Now you can simply remove the background from all frames with a subtraction.  Additionally, you could try  subtracting the previous 1 (or several) frames from the current frame to highlight the  changes between frames (effectively a time derivative).  This could be done in a loop.
2. **Sum along rows and columns** -- column and row projections are a very easy way to highlight high contrast regions within an image.  Presumably (if dark values > light values) column summing an image where the fish was in the middle of the image would yield a Gaussian looking vector with a peak index corresponding to the middle column of the image (see figure below).  This would also give you a means to estimate the size of the fish by noting the width of the Gaussian looking vector.

[image]

Note that the initial high values on the column sum vector are a result of the lighting conditions and would be remedied via background removal (see step 1).

From the numpy package in python you can perform column sums with something like:

```
 import numpy as np
 np.sum(M,axis=1)
```

Where M is the current image/matrix/frame of interest.

Comment: How do I average the frames with no fish? I'm getting what you're saying but I don't how to translate that to code. Thanks.

Comment: I've also added 1 more example of 1 fish passing with backlighting

Comment: I added an example of how to average 3 frames in my original post.  Basically you add N number of background frames (without fish) together and divide that sum by N.  Then whenever you read in a frame, the first step is to remove that averaged (background) matrix from the current frame/image/matrix.